# How to access the page attribute from code in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to build a custom tag helper in `ASP.NET Core` razor pages, and I want to be able to know in which page am I now.

Currently, the only option I know is to use the following code:

`HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Trim('/').ToLower()`

But this option is very ugly, especially when we use pages like `MyPage/Edit` or `MyPage/Create`. So, what I want is to get only `MyPage`.

**I am using ASP.NET Core 3.0**

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to get the current page name or the current URL?

Comment: I want to return ```MyPage``` only from expression like ```asp-page="\MyPage\Edit"``` used in cshtml file, so I want to access MyPage value from the code behind

Comment: So you want the folder name?

Comment: yes, can be done by defining default routing and to use page instead of controller?

Comment: Controller? Are you using MVC or Razor Pages?

Comment: I am using razor pages. But I was wondering if applicable to make something like ```routes.MapRoute("default", "{page=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")``` and later I can access the page value as ```ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"]```

Comment: You can, but you're looking for `PageContext`, not `ViewContext`.